# sed replace if part of word matches

Tags: sed

My text looks like this:

> cat
>   catch
>   cat_mouse
>   catty

I want to replace "cat" with "dog".
When I do

> sed "s/cat/dog/"

my result is:

> dog
>   catch
>   cat_mouse
>   catty

How do I replace with sed if only part of the word matches?

Comment: Are you sure?  `sed 's/cat/dog/'` should make a replacement in the line `cat_mouse`.  Have you represented your input data correctly.  (eg, is it actually all on one line, and not on distinct lines?)

Comment: Better provide what you expect as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake : 
You lack the `g` modifier

```
sed 's/cat/dog/g'
```

> g
>
> ```
> Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.
> ```

See

- http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html
- http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.1.3

Comment: This is irrelevant unless the questioner has misrepresented the input data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace only *cat* by *dog* only if part of the word matches :

```
$ perl -pe 's/cat(?=.)/dog/' file.txt
cat
dogch
dog_mouse
dogty
```

I use Positive Look Around, see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

If you really want sed :

```
sed '/^cat$/!s/cat/dog/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bash-3.00$ cat t
cat
catch
cat_mouse
catty
```

To replace `cat` only if it is part of a string

```
bash-3.00$ sed 's/cat\([^$]\)/dog\1/' t
cat
dogch
dog_mouse
dogty
```

To replace all occurrences of `cat`:

```
bash-3.00$ sed 's/cat/dog/' t
dog
dogch
dog_mouse
dogty
```

Answer (score 1):

awk solution for this

`awk '{gsub("cat","dog",$0); print}' temp.txt`